# vbscript replacing text without overwriting in a text file

Tags: vbscript

Below is part of a script I already wrote:

```
For i = 1 to arrsize 
    strText=""
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(filetable(i), ForReading)
    wscript.echo filetable(i)
    On Error Resume Next
        Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
            strline = objFile.ReadLine
            If instr(strline, source_string) > 0 Then
                wscript.echo strline
                Do Until instr(strline, " TEXT ") > 0 or instr(strline, Chr(9) & "TEXT ") 
                    strline = objFile.ReadLine
            Loop
                strNewText = Replace(strline, "TEXT " & Chr(34), "TEXT " & Chr(34) & "Critical: ",1,-1,0)
                wscript.echo strNewText
'up to here everything is OK

            Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(filetable(i), ForWriting)
                objFile.WriteLine strNewText
                objFile.close
'The three line above are overwriting the text file
            End If`enter code here`
        Loop
Next
```

My script is to search in an array of files for a specific string registered in source_string variable, then if it matches it should search for "TEXT" word preceded by space or tab, when matches and it should it will then replace the line with the same line as per the following format:
TEXT "Critical: ****".
I hope it is clear and thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For i = 1 to arrsize
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(filetable(i), ForReading)
wscript.echo filetable(i)
On Error Resume Next
Dim filearray()
Linenb = 0
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    Linenb = Linenb + 1
    Redim Preserve filearray(Linenb)
    filearray(Linenb) = objFile.ReadLine
'       wscript.echo filearray(Linenb)
        If instr(filearray(Linenb), source_string) > 0 Then
'           wscript.echo filearray(Linenb)
            Do Until instr(filearray(Linenb), " TEXT ") > 0 or instr(filearray(Linenb), Chr(9) & "TEXT ") 
                Linenb = Linenb + 1
                Redim Preserve filearray (Linenb)
                filearray(Linenb) = objFile.ReadLine
'               wscript.echo filearray(Linenb)
            Loop
            filearray(Linenb) = Replace(filearray(Linenb), "TEXT " & Chr(34), "TEXT " & Chr(34) & "Critical: ",1,-1,0)
'           wscript.echo filearray(Linenb)
        End If
Loop
For j = 1 to Linenb
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(filetable(i), ForWriting)
    objfile.WriteLine filearray(j)
Next
Redim Preserve filearray (1)
```

Next

Answer (score 1):

I think here you open the text file again and you start at the start of stream and thus the first line (and not the found line) :

```
        Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(filetable(i), ForWriting)
            objFile.WriteLine strNewText
            objFile.close
```

Maybe you should try opening the file for reading&writing, readline, when you str is found, then change that line and move on ...

Comment: Sorry could you please verify; I am newbie on vbscript. Is there anyway to replace the found text instead of overwriting all contents

Comment: Yes, when you start reading your file, `Readline` returns a string, so that's when you search for your target string and then you get you `strNewText`. Now, you are still in the same line, don't close the file or jump to the next line, just `writeline(strNexText)`and then jump to the next line until you reach the `EndofStream`.

Comment: I tried it this way, but the script does not continue (with no prompt) and nothing is written to the file

Comment: Sorry it does write to the file; again the script does not continue and it overwrite the contents of the file with strNewText

Comment: What kind of files are you opening ? and do they have line returns ?

Comment: Yes they have returns and they do not have extensions; their names are something like ********-*****-*********-*****_data

Comment: Ah I have rechecked and it appeared to be that ForWriting option overwrites everything. It deletes data in file and insert new data ...
So, I don't know if there's a method to Read/Write at the same time. But, you can try to get your text file into an array of strings or just one string if the size is small and do your replacements there and then write to the file. 
However, if the files are quite large, it's going to be war with the memory.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try it and will wait if there are any other suggestions

Comment: Thanks; your suggestion is working; I will submit the solution